# Output the legendary Yggdrasil

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Your task is to output a representation of the legendary tree of life, [Yggdrasil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yggdrasil).

You must write a program whose output is exactly that :

```
                                       /\
                                      /**\
                                     /****\
                                    /******\
                                    /******\
                                   /********\
                                  /**********\
                                 /************\
                                /**************\
                                 /************\
                                /**************\
                               /****************\
                              /******************\
                             /********************\
                            /**********************\
                              /******************\
                             /********************\
                            /**********************\
                           /************************\
                          /**************************\
                         /****************************\
                        /******************************\
                           /************************\
                          /**************************\
                         /****************************\
                        /******************************\
                       /********************************\
                      /**********************************\
                     /************************************\
                    /**************************************\
                        /******************************\
                       /********************************\
                      /**********************************\
                     /************************************\
                    /**************************************\
                   /****************************************\
                  /******************************************\
                 /********************************************\
                /**********************************************\
                     /************************************\
                    /**************************************\
                   /****************************************\
                  /******************************************\
                 /********************************************\
                /**********************************************\
               /************************************************\
              /**************************************************\
             /****************************************************\
            /******************************************************\
                  /******************************************\
                 /********************************************\
                /**********************************************\
               /************************************************\
              /**************************************************\
             /****************************************************\
            /******************************************************\
           /********************************************************\
          /**********************************************************\
         /************************************************************\
        /**************************************************************\
               /************************************************\
              /**************************************************\
             /****************************************************\
            /******************************************************\
           /********************************************************\
          /**********************************************************\
         /************************************************************\
        /**************************************************************\
       /****************************************************************\
      /******************************************************************\
     /********************************************************************\
    /**********************************************************************\
            /******************************************************\
           /********************************************************\
          /**********************************************************\
         /************************************************************\
        /**************************************************************\
       /****************************************************************\
      /******************************************************************\
     /********************************************************************\
    /**********************************************************************\
   /************************************************************************\
  /**************************************************************************\
 /****************************************************************************\
/******************************************************************************\
                                   |--------|
                                   |--------|
                                   |--------|
                                   |--------|
                                   |--------|
                                   |--------|
                                   |--------|
                                   |--------|
                                   |--------|
                                   |--------|
                                   |--------|
                                   |________|
```

There is no trailing whitespace. The final newline may be omitted.

To make checking easier, here are the md5 sums of the expected output:

- `374899e56bc854d04639c43120642e37` - No newline at end.
- `03afb81d960b8e130fe2f9e0906f0482` - Newline at end

Standard loopholes apply.
This is code-golf, so the smallest entry in bytes win!

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15860/15599 . Nax, you should work in marketing. Every household is going to want a Yggdrasil this Christmas. I see you answered the Graham's number question too. You must like pointy things. Let's have some new names for "rocket" and "ice cream cone."

Comment: Also related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4244/194 .

Comment: @Nax: since the world tree has fruit, and angiosperms don't, and that is clearly a confiner of some description, unfortunately it looks like you took a picture of the wrong tree :P

Comment: @Nax Hmm. You are correct. The pedant (me) is hoist on his own petard. The md5sums have changed.

Comment: Err, point of order, Yggdrasil is definitely an ash tree in the eddas, not a fir. [Kinda like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fraxinus_excelsior_-_Ardenne_1b.JPG).

Answer (score 22):

## Golfscript, <s>84</s> <s>[77](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MTAsey40KjQrLFwzKj57LjM5XC0nICcqJy8nQDIqJyonKidcXCdufS99LzEyLHsnICczNSonfCdAJ18tJ1wxMTxbPV04Kid8JytufS8%3D)</s> <s>[76](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MTAsey40KjQrLFwzKj57LjM5XC0nICcqJy8nQDIqJyonKidcXCdufS99LzEyLHsnICczNSonfCdAMTE8J18tJ1s9XTgqJ3wnK259Lw%3D%3D)</s> <s>[75](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MTAsey40KjQrLFwzKj57LjM5XC0nICcqJy8nQDIqJyonKidcXCdufS99LzEyLHsnICczNSonfCdAMTE8J18tJ1s9XTgqMSQrbn0v)</s> [72](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MTAsey4pNCosXDMqPnsuMzlcLScgJyonLydAMionKicqJ1wKJ30vfS8xMix7JyAnMzUqJ3wnQDExPCdfLScxLz04KjEkbn0v) characters

Different approach from [Howard's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36442/4800). Click on the character count to try it.

```
10,{.)4*,\3*>{.39\-' '*'/'@2*'*'*'\
'}/}/12,{' '35*'|'@11<'_-'1/=8*1$n}/
```

Thanks to Howard for saving 3 characters!

**Explanation**:

This is more or less a straightforward port of [my Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36439/4800). Taking some expressive liberties (using named variables instead of keeping track of stack positions, and `print` is really keeping things on the stack, not printing):

```
10,{...}/            # for i in range(10):
   .                 #    x = i
   )4*,              #    Y = range((i+1)*4)
   \3*               #    x *= 3
   >                 #    Y = Y[x:]  # y is now range(3*i, (i+1)*4)
   {...}/            #    for j in Y:
      .39\-          #        q = 39 - j
      ' '*           #        print ' '*q  # print right number of spaces
      '/'            #        print '/'
      @2*            #        j *= 2
      '*'*           #        print '*'*j
      '\<NEWLINE>'   #        print "\\\n"
12,{...}/            # for i in range(12):
    ' '35*           #    print ' '*35
    '|'              #    print '|'
    @11<             #    i = i < 11
    '_-'1/=          #    z = "_-"[i] # pick "-" if i < 11, else pick "_"
    8*               #    print z*8
    1$               #    print '|' # (copy from earlier in the stack)
    n                #    print "\n"
```

Comment: You may use the same line-break trick as in my solution. Instead of `'\\'n` pull the newline into the string (+/- 0 characters) and now the backslash no longer needs to be escaped (-1 character).

Comment: Two more: `4*4+` is the same as `)4*` and `'_-'[=]` can be written `'_-'1/=` which makes the last `+` obsolete.

Comment: an explanation could be useful...? is this too much to ask?

Comment: @professorfish: Coming right up!

Comment: Don't you need a trailing ';' here? Otherwise there will be two trailing newlines since golfscript by default adds one.

Answer (score 22):

## [Haml](http://haml.info/) & [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

## 37 + 277 = 314

**Haml:**

```
%link(rel="stylesheet" href="s")
%pre
```

**Sass:**

```
pre:after{$l:"";@for$k from0 to10{@for$i from0 to4+$k{@for$j from0 to40-($k*6+$i*2)/2{$l:$l+' ';}$l:$l+'/';@for$j from0 to$k*6+$i*2{$l:$l+'*';}$l:$l+"\\\a ";}}@for$i from0 to12{@for$j from0 to35{$l:$l+" ";}@if$i<11{$l:$l+"|--------|\a ";}@else{$l:$l+"|________|";}}content:$l;}
```

*Sass allows control directives, concatenation, and variable dereference.  All of which are useful when styling, but verbose while golfing.

---

*gets generated into:*

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="s" /><pre></pre>
```

**CSS:**

```
pre:after {
  content: "                                        /\\\a                                        /**\\\a                                       /****\\\a                                      /******\\\a                                      /******\\\a                                     /********\\\a                                    /**********\\\a                                   /************\\\a                                  /**************\\\a                                   /************\\\a                                  /**************\\\a                                 /****************\\\a                                /******************\\\a                               /********************\\\a                              /**********************\\\a                                /******************\\\a                               /********************\\\a                              /**********************\\\a                             /************************\\\a               
             /**************************\\\a                           /****************************\\\a                          /******************************\\\a                             /************************\\\a                            /**************************\\\a                           /****************************\\\a                          /******************************\\\a                         /********************************\\\a                        /**********************************\\\a                       /************************************\\\a                      /**************************************\\\a                          /******************************\\\a                         /********************************\\\a                        /**********************************\\\a                       /************************************\\\a                      /**************************************\\\a                     /******************************
**********\\\a                    /******************************************\\\a                   /********************************************\\\a                  /**********************************************\\\a                       /************************************\\\a                      /**************************************\\\a                     /****************************************\\\a                    /******************************************\\\a                   /********************************************\\\a                  /**********************************************\\\a                 /************************************************\\\a                /**************************************************\\\a               /****************************************************\\\a              /******************************************************\\\a                    /******************************************\\\a                   /**********************************
**********\\\a                  /**********************************************\\\a                 /************************************************\\\a                /**************************************************\\\a               /****************************************************\\\a              /******************************************************\\\a             /********************************************************\\\a            /**********************************************************\\\a           /************************************************************\\\a          /**************************************************************\\\a                 /************************************************\\\a                /**************************************************\\\a               /****************************************************\\\a              /******************************************************\\\a             /*****************************************************
***\\\a            /**********************************************************\\\a           /************************************************************\\\a          /**************************************************************\\\a         /****************************************************************\\\a        /******************************************************************\\\a       /********************************************************************\\\a      /**********************************************************************\\\a              /******************************************************\\\a             /********************************************************\\\a            /**********************************************************\\\a           /************************************************************\\\a          /**************************************************************\\\a         /****************************************************************\\\a        /*********
*********************************************************\\\a       /********************************************************************\\\a      /**********************************************************************\\\a     /************************************************************************\\\a    /**************************************************************************\\\a   /****************************************************************************\\\a  /******************************************************************************\\\a                                    |--------|\a                                    |--------|\a                                    |--------|\a                                    |--------|\a                                    |--------|\a                                    |--------|\a                                    |--------|\a                                    |--------|\a                                    |--------|\a                                    
|--------|\a                                    |--------|\a                                    |________|"; }
```

---

*the resulting [page](http://luxe.github.io/code-golf/Yggdrasil/)*

Comment: You don't see a ton of HTML/CSS solutions on CodeGolf. Nice job.

Answer (score 16):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 62 bytes

```
A,{I4+,{I3*J+_39\-S*'/@2*'**'\N}fJ}fI{35S*'|'-8*'|N++}C*'-/'_*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/31Gn2tNEG0gYa3lpxxtbxugGa6nrOxhpqWtpqcf41aZ51aZ5VhubAkVr1HUtgKSftnats5a6rr56vNb//wA)

#### How it works

```
A,           " Push [ 0  …  9 ].                                                   ";
{            " For each I in that array:                                           ";
  I4+,       " Push [ 0  …  I + 3 ].                                               ";
  {          " For each J in that array:                                           ";
    I3*J+_   " Push K := 3 * I + J twice.                                          ";
    39\-S*   " Push a string consisting of 39 - K spaces.                          ";
    '/       " Push a slash.                                                       ";
    @2*'**   " Push a string consisting of 2 * K asterisks.                        ";
    '\N      " Push a backslash and a linefeed.                                    ";
  }fJ        "                                                                     ";
}fI          "                                                                     ";
{            " Do the following 12 times:                                          ";
  35S*       " Push a string consisting of 35 spaces.                              ";
  '|         " Push a vertical bar.                                                ";
  '-8*'|++   " Push the string '--------|\n'.                                      ";
}C*          "                                                                     ";
'-/'_*       " Replace the hyphen-minus signs of the last string with underscores. ";
```

Comment: I've got to start using CJam instead of GolfScript...

Comment: What makes CJam code so compact? Is it just usual features match together well or there is some super-trick? Or it's actually not CJam, but CJam programmers so?

Comment: @Vi.: It's a mix of both. 1. CJam is stack based, so you usually get away without using any variables. 2. All built-ins' names are at most two characters long. Because of this, you don't need whitespace except for some special cases. 3. Even submissions in golfing languages don't golf themselves. My GolfScript/CJam programs are a lot shorter now than they used to be.

Comment: Suggestion for CJam would be to use ASCII codes 128-256 for a whole nother set of built-ins. have some special editor that

Comment: @Claudiu: Well, that's up to its creator. If I designed my own golfing language, I think I would make it bit-based or encode all instructions arithmetically.

Comment: Your _Try it online._ link only links to the blank interpreter without your source code.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Yes, that was before the interpreter had permalinks. Fixed.

Answer (score 15):

#### GolfScript, 79 characters

```
10,{:^4+,{2*^6*+'*'*.,2/~40+' '*'/'@'\
'}/}/[' '35*]12*'|--------|
'*'||''_'8**
```

Try the code [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MTAsezpeNCssezIqXjYqKycqJyouLDIvfjQwKycgJyonLydAJ1wKJ30vfS9bJyAnMzUqXTEyKid8LS0tLS0tLS18CicqJ3x8JydfJzgqKg%3D%3D&run=true). Note that the line breaks aren't optional in this code

Comment: A multi-line GolfScript solution? I didn't think I'd see the day!

Answer (score 13):

## Python, <s>148</s> <s>129</s> <s>126</s> 121 characters

```
R=range
for i in R(10):
 for j in R(i*3,4+i*4):print' '*(39-j)+'/'+'**'*j+'\\'
for c in'-'*11+'_':print' '*35+'|'+c*8+'|'
```

Thanks to [Falko](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36431/output-the-legendary-yggdrasil/36439?noredirect=1#comment81623_36439) for saving 3 characters and to [flornquake](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36431/output-the-legendary-yggdrasil/36439?noredirect=1#comment81902_36439) for brilliantly saving another 5!

Comment: Python's character multiplication is a bit too perfect for this challenge...

Comment: Wait 'till you see my golfscript solution... =P

Comment: Use ```'**'*j``` to save 3 characters. Apart from this my solution converges to the exact same code. :)

Comment: You can make the last line shorter by writing `for c in'-'*11+'_':print' '*35+'|'+c*8+'|'`.

Comment: @flornquake: nice! very clever

Answer (score 12):

## Bash, <del>236 197</del> 193

10 bytes of code + 1-byte filename + 182-byte data file = 193 bytes total

```
zcat y 2>j
```

### Explanation

`y` is a file containing the Yggdrasil, without a trailing new line, compressed with the [zopfli](https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/) algorithm (invoked as `zopfli --i64`) and then with the last 8 bytes removed. zopfli is compatible with gzip, so I can decompress the file with standard Bash utilities designed for gzip. The size of the data file is 182 bytes (229 bytes when normal gzip is used). The size of the original Yggdrasil, without the trailing new line, is 5876 bytes.

The removal of the last 8 bytes causes error messages, which are suppressed by sending standard error to a file called `j`. If `j` exists, it will be overwritten.

The base64 of `y` is (use `base64 -d` to obtain the original file):

```
H4sIAAAAAAACA+3SMQoCURDA0N5TWC+IFxK8yD/8Nul9hfDRnamT6J+du83zdUPwOACNNDb0+3Bs
tMPhSscDvusHgM9wIcUNclL+5r/luJXkmlh5rM3r8txkMdVNcEn1Nc2a1AU72XWz3Xd91r5z7eZD
AQKQgAI0PDFf8xJfExpQgQhkpAIdz8ytzK3AQMg6UMIQpLQELU/NQc5B/thBegtqHpOc16jHOX/v
x1mPZg19MfrdrBM=
```

And the md5sum is:

```
4a049a80241160cdde0a3cbca323b7f2
```

Comment: My finger was itching to hit the "delete" button when I saw the code, until I read the character count and explanation. :P

Comment: You can save about 30 bytes by using zopfli to make the compressed file.  "zopfli --i100 y" yields a 190-byte file that zcat can decompress.

Comment: And a few more if you delete the last 10 bytes and close STDERR.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson thanks for pointing this out, I've also edited my answer to 'Molar masses of compounds' http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35613/16402 to use zopfli, saving 37 bytes

Comment: @Dennis it turned out to be 8 bytes (any more and bits of the Yggdrasil's trunk would be missing), thanks

Comment: For me this is a totally fresh idea - yay!  Much more interesting than the "standard" GolfScript solutions, clever though they are.

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby - 100

```ruby
puts (0..21).map{|i|i>9??\ *35+?|+(i>20??_:?-)*8+?|:(0..i+3).map{|y|?\ *(39-z=y+3*i)+?/+?**z*2+?\\}}
```

Puts auto-flattens, so we can collect all the lines even in nested arrays. Needs Ruby 1.9

Try at [ideone](http://ideone.com/7FvXVA)

Comment: I think it needs some leading spaces. Also, works with Ruby 1.9, but not in 1.8.

Answer (score 7):

## C, 169

```
i;j;p(a,b){while(b--)putchar(a);}main(){for(;i++<10;)for(j=i*3-4;++j<i*4;p(32,39-j),p(47,1),p(42,j*2),puts("\\"));for(++i;i--;p(32,35),p(124,1),p(i?45:95,8),puts("|"));}
```

Ungolfed (and slightly disentangled):

```
int i;
int j;
void p(a,b) {
  while (b--) putchar(a);
}
void main() {
  for (;i++<10;) {
    for (j=i*3-4;++j<i*4;) {
      p(32,39-j);
      p(47,1);
      p(42,j*2);
      puts("\\");
    }
  }
  for (++i;i--;) {
    p(32,35);
    p(124,1);
    p(i?45:95,8);
    puts("|");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## PowerShell <s>104</s> 101

```
0..9|%{(3*$_)..(3+$_*4)|%{" "*(39-$_)+"/"+"*"*2*$_+"\"}};0..11|%{" "*35+"|"+("-","_")[$_-eq11]*8+"|"}
```

Answer (score 6):

### C# <s>258</s> 234bytes

Thanks to some annoymous user for the suggested edits making good use of the String.PadLeft method!

```c#
using System;class G{static void Main(){Action<string>p=Console.WriteLine;int i=0,j;for(;i++<10;)for(j=i*3-3;j++<i*4;)p("/".PadLeft(41-j)+"\\".PadLeft(2*j-1,'*'));while(i-->0)p("|--------|".PadLeft(45));p("|________|".PadLeft(45));}}
```

The code is pretty simple, not much left to golf.

Formatted code:

```c#
using System;
class G
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action<string> p = Console.WriteLine;
        int i = 0, j;
        for(; i++ < 10 ;)
            for(j = i*3 - 3; j++ < i*4;)
                p("/".PadLeft(41 - j) + "\\".PadLeft(2*j - 1,'*'));
        while(i-- > 0)
            p("|--------|".PadLeft(45));
        p("|________|".PadLeft(45));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `\r` is pointless here. This is code golf.

Comment: @nyuszika7h indeed, but it's included in the formatted copy for good measure so that people using notepad can more easily see the glory of the Yggdrasil (it's not included in the score)

Comment: Oh, I see. Windows... Feel free to fix my edit then.

Comment: @nyuszika7h thanks for pointing out the Syntax Highlighting wasn't right

Answer (score 6):

### J, <s>98 88 84</s> 75

```
(85 11 1#3 4$' /*\ |-| |_|')#"1~(39&-,1,+:,1:)"0(12$4),~85(-4&+#-:*>:)&i.10
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby - <s>139</s> <s>129</s> <s>126</s> <s>123</s> 121

Hoisted "puts" outside of array creation (suggestion from bitpwner).

```
puts (0..9).map{|i|(i*3...(i+1)*4).map{|j|"/#{'**'*j}\\".rjust(41+j,' ')}}+["%45s"%'|--------|']*11<<'%45s'%'|________|'
```

Ungolfed ("puts" unhoisted):

```
# print fill patterns from the intervals
# [0..3, 3..7, 6..11, 9..15, 12..19, 15..23, 18..27, 21..31, 24..35, 27..39]
# centered on columns 81-82
(0..9).each { |i|
  (i*3...(i+1)*4).each { |j|    # x...y vs x..y-1 saves a char
    puts "/#{'**'*j}\\".rjust(41+j,' ')
  }
}
# print the stump
puts ("%45s\n" % '|--------|') * 11
puts '%45s' % '|________|'
```

Comment: @bitpwner I think this deserves it's own answer. Go for it.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 127

```
for$i(0..9){for$j($i*3..3+$i*4){print" "x(39-$j),"/","*"x($j*2),"\\\n";}}for$i(0..11){print" "x35,"|",($i>10?"_":"-")x8,"|\n";}
```

#### Ungolfed:

```
for $i (0..9) {
  for $j ($i*3..3+$i*4) {
    print " "x(39-$j) , "/" , "*"x($j*2) , "\\\n";
  }
}
for $i (0..11) {
  print " "x35 , "|" , ($i>10?"_":"-")x8 , "|\n";
}
```

Comment: Replace $i with $_ and save 4 characters.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP <strike>223</strike> <strike>202</strike> <strike>181</strike> <strike>160</strike> 156

Edit I figured out how to alias a function with a variable and was able to chop off some more characters. That `str_repeat` function was really verbose

Edit 2: Thanks everyone for the suggestions!

Golfed:

```php
<?$s=str_repeat;for($i=-1;$i++<9;)for($j=$i*3;$j<4+$i*4;)echo$s(' ',39-$j).'/'.$s('**',$j++)."\\
";for($i=12;$i--;)echo$s(' ',35),'|'.$s($i?'-':'_',8)."|
";
```

Readable:

```php
    <?

$s=str_repeat;

for($i=-1;$i++<9;)
{
    for($j=$i*3;$j<4+$i*4;)
    {
        echo$s(' ',39-$j).'/'.$s('**',$j++)."\\
        ";
    }
}

for($i=12;$i--;)
{
    echo$s(' ',35),'|'.$s($i?'-':'_',8)."|
    ";
}
```

Output: http://brobin.me/yggdrasil.php

Comment: You can save 6 chars by removing parenthesis around `(39-$j)`, `($j*2)` and `($i==11)`. -2 by replacing `\n` with real new line characters (PHP allows it in litterals). -5 chars by replacing (both) `for($i=0;$i<12;$i++)` with `for($i=12;$i-->0;)` and `$i==11` with `$i==0`.

Comment: After that you can also replace `$s(($i==0?'_':'-'),8)` with `$s($i?'-':'_',8)`. (==> -5 chars)

Comment: -1 Character by replacing `$s('*',$j*2)` with `$s('**',$j)`. I think that's the last improvement that I can find.

Comment: -2 changing `($j*2)` in inner for to `($j++*2)` and removing `$j++` from `for()` arguments

Comment: @sebcap26 `for($i=12;$i-->0;)` can be shortened to `for($i=12;$i--;)` - another 2 chars.

Comment: @avall Nice ! I made a fiddle With all our modifications (I'm not sure if we should edit the answer) : http://jsfiddle.net/ckqhqxh1/

Comment: I just made the edits. Thanks everyone for your sugggestions! Chopped 19 characters off.

Comment: 2 errors: swap `'_':'-'` to `'-':'_'` and write `$j++` in second use of `$j`, not first.

Comment: -2 for changing `for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)` to `for($i=-1;$i++<9;)`

Comment: -2 for changing first characters to `$s=str_repeat`, and -1 for removing `\n` and simply pressing an enter there.

Comment: You can remove `$i=0` if you use the `-n` flag. And a general hint: using `str_pad` is almost always shorter than `str_repeat`.

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript, <strike>288</strike> 281

Chrome hides duplicated `console.log`s, use IE instead.

```
function t(w){s="";for(i=0;i++<39-w;)s+=" ";s+="/";for(i=0;i++<w*2;)s+="*";return s+"\\"}function r(l){s="";for(i=0;i++<36;)s+=" ";s+="|";for(i=0;i++<8;)s+=l;return s+"|"}w=0;c=console;for(h=0;h++<10;){for(j=0;j++<3+h;)c.log(t(w++));w-=h}for(j=0;j++<11;)c.log(r('-'));c.log(r('_'))
```

Ungolfed:

```
function t(w)
{
    s="";
    for(i=0;i++<39-w;)
        s+=" ";
    s+="/";
    for(i=0;i++<w*2;)
        s+="*";
    return s+"\\"
}
function r(l)
{
    s="";
    for(i=0;i++<36;)
        s+=" ";
    s+="|";
    for(i=0;i++<8;)
        s+=l;
    return s+"|"
}

w=0;
c=console;
for(h=0;h++<10;)
{
    for(j=0;j++<3+h;)
        c.log(t(w++));
    w-=h;
}
for(j=0;j++<11;)
    c.log(r('-'));
c.log(r('_'))
```

Comment: Use `for(i=0;i++<39-w;)` instead of `for(i=0;i<39-w;++i)`, and so on. Also, `p=console.log` instead of `c=console` and `p` instead of `c.log` (although I only tested the latter in Node.js, it doesn't work in Firefox). This saves 12 bytes.

Comment: `c=console.log` didn't work in Chrome either, so I didn't use it. The for loop tricks save 7 bytes though.

Comment: I'm usually quite wary of anything *encouraging* me to use MSIE...

Comment: This is quite possibly the first time I've ever seen the phrase "use IE instead." O_o However, you can suppress Chrome's behavior by simply running this code in the console instead of from a webpage.

Comment: Running it in a page and in the console produces the same results for me on both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

## Delphi 429

Will try to improve later.
Golfed

```
uses strutils,SysUtils,Classes;const a='|----';b='|____';c:array [0..9,0..1]of int32=((0,3),(3,7),(6,11),(9,15),(12,19),(15,23),(18,27),(21,31),(24,35),(27,39));var t:TStrings;i,j:integer;begin t:=tstringlist.Create;for I:=0to 9do for J:=c[i,0]to c[i,1]do t.Add('/'+StringOfChar('*',j));for I:=0to 10do t.Add(a);t.Add(b);for I:=0to t.Count-1do t[i]:=t[i].PadLeft(40)+ReverseString(t[i]).Replace('/','\');write(T.TEXT);readln;end.
```

ungolfed

```
uses
  strutils,SysUtils,Classes;
const
  a='|----';
  b='|____';
  c:array [0..9,0..1]of int32=((0,3),(3,7),(6,11),(9,15),(12,19),(15,23),(18,27),(21,31),(24,35),(27,39));
var
  t:TStrings;
  i,j:integer;
begin
  t:=tstringlist.Create;
  for I:=0to 9do
    for J:=c[i,0]to c[i,1]do
      t.Add('/'+StringOfChar('*',j));
  for I:=0to 10do
    t.Add(a);
  t.Add(b);
  for I:=0to t.Count-1do
    t[i]:=t[i].PadLeft(40)+ReverseString(t[i]).Replace('/','\');
  write(T.TEXT);
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

## C (219)

Thanks to everyone for the golfing tips -- managed to get it down to 219.  Don't think it'll go much lower.

```cplusplus
w,W,s,S,i,r;main(){char T[78];memset(T,42,78);for(r=4,s=39;r<14;++r,s-=3,w+=6)for(i=0,S=s,W=w;i<r;++i,W+=2,--S)printf("%*s/%.*s\\\n",S,"",W,T);for(i=0;i<11;i++)printf("%35s|--------|\n","");printf("%35s|________|","");}
```

Required includes:

```cplusplus
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: If he's willing to use C89 he can omit all the includes as well. There is no case in this code where implicit declaration on call screws up.

Comment: @Nax; that gets me to 263 -- and I pulled includes out.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joshua -- 64 bit systems and memset could be problematic, but...otherwise, maybe not.  Either way, most people remove the includes, so I did, too.

Comment: It's actually 262 characters, you don't need the trailing newline.

Comment: You can use `32` instead of `' '` and `42` instead of  `'*'` :)

Comment: s/w2/b, s/s2/c .

Comment: Quick suggestions: global implicit ints, drop `S`, use int for space and asterisk for 228 bytes. `w,w2,s2,i;main(){int r=4,s=39;char T[78];memset(T,42,78);for(;r<14;++r,s-=3,w+=6)for(i=0,s2=s,w2=w;i<r;++i,w2+=2,--s2)printf("%*s/%.*s\\\n",s2,"",w2,T);for(i=0;i<11;i++)printf("%35s|--------|\n","");printf("%35s|________|","");}`

Comment: Thanks y'all...I'll keep these in mind for future golfs.  Somehow I just have issues writing golf'd code; I guess keeping code quasi-readable has been pounded in me too hard, lol.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (console.log), <s>168</s> 166

(Whitespace for readability only)

```javascript
for(i=c=0;i<11;i++)
  for(j=0;j<4+i&!c;j++)
    l=i*13+j,
    a=Array(n=i-10?3*i+j+1:5).join("*-_"[k=(l>129)+(c=l==141)]),
    console.log(Array(41-n).join(" ")+'/||'[k]+a+a+'\\||'[k])
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>153</s> 148

Straight-forward, no tricks, just plain golfing:

```
(a:b:c)%n=(39-n)&' '++a:(2*n)&b++c
n#m=[n..m]++(n+3)#(m+4)
(&)=replicate
main=putStr$unlines$map("/*\\"%)(take 85$0#3)++map("|-|"%)(11&4)++["|_|"%4]
```

The `%` operator draws a single line, its first argument being a `String` of length 3 containing the borders and the fill characters in that line (now assuming exactly 3 `Char`s, saving 5 bytes), the second, an `Int`, specifies half the number of fill characters.  Pattern matching, cons-ing and appending is used in combination in order to save bytes by taking care of the "glue" between `Char` and `String`.  In this second version, I also made `#` infinite and introduced a `take 85` to make it finite again (no bytes saved, unfortunately).

The `#` operator creates the sequence for the `n` argument to `%` required for the tree: `[0..3], [3..7], ...` concatenated.

`&` is just an infix shorthand for `replicate`, which occurs three times.

The tree is put together in the last line, the newlines are added by `unlines`.

Comment: [138 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYyxCoMwFAB3v0KSii8@TCu6GOoftFPHGCSIUKlasRaj5N/TdLu74Z768@qGwTmIWLV089C3eu0CMGIXB6NbBXmZbiyKwxjRCIANve0M8QhG3U/VqOd7E87f9bEut@nUvic/kL4COSd1TSiTJsk5z9EkhbLmmsoL56VSiFkWAbGpJbTwP0ls80fl3A8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### Lua - [164](http://repl.it/XHD)

```
a=' 'for i=0,9 do for j=i*3,3+i*4 do print(a:rep(39-j)..'/'..(('*'):rep(j*2))..'\\')end end for i=0,11 do print(a:rep(35)..'|'..((i>10 and'_'or'-'):rep(8))..'|')end
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mathematica <s>191</s> 178**

For sure not the best solution:

```
n=Nest;
t=Table;
""<>
    t[
        {n[#<>" "&,"",39-i],"/",n[#<>"*"&,"",2i],"\\\n"}
    ,
        {i,Flatten@t[Range[j+4]-1+3j,{j,0,9}]}
    ]
<>
    t[
        n[#<>" "&,"",35]<>If[i==12,"|________|\n","|--------|\n"]
    ,
        {i,12}
    ]
```

Not counting newlines.
Mathematica skews the output, as it doesn't take the same width for a whitespace as for "*" and "/". But the result is correct.

Comment: (it's my first golf)

Answer (score 2):

## Java - 286

My first golf.

Golfed:

```
class M{public static void main(String[]args){int i=0,a,f=0;String s="";for(;i++<11;){for(a=i*3-4;++a<i*4;){if(i>10){a=4;if(++f>12)break;}s+=s.format("%"+(40-a)+"s"+(a>0?"%0"+a+"d":"")+"%3$s",f>0?"|":"/",0,f>0?"|":"\\").replace("0",f<1?"**":f>11?"__":"--")+"\n";}}System.out.println(s);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
class M {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0,a,f=0;
        String s = "";
        for(;i++<11;){
            for(a=i*3-4;++a<i*4;a++){
                if(i>10){
                    a=4;
                    if(++f>12)break;
                }
                s+=s.format("%"+(40-a)+"s"+(a>0?"%0"+a+"d":"")+"%3$s",f>0?"|":"/", 0,f>0?"|":"\\").replace("0", f<1?"**":f>11?"__":"--")+"\n";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

[Test here](http://ideone.com/zbCHMW)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 117

```python
j=0
while j<40:j-=j/4;exec(j/3+4)*r"print' '*(39-j)+'/'+'**'*j+'\\';j+=1;"
for c in'-'*11+'_':print' '*35+'|'+c*8+'|'
```

---

Other versions I tried include:

```python
# 118
for i in range(10):j=i*3;exec(i+4)*r"print' '*(39-j)+'/'+'**'*j+'\\';j+=1;"
for c in'-'*11+'_':print' '*35+'|'+c*8+'|'

# 118
i=j=4
while j:j=52-3*i;exec"j-=1;print' '*j+'/'+'**'*(39-j)+'\\\\';"*i;i+=1
for c in'-'*11+'_':print' '*35+'|'+c*8+'|'

# 118
j=0
for b in'\\'*10:j-=j/4;exec(j/3+4)*"print' '*(39-j)+'/'+'**'*j+b;j+=1;"
for c in'-'*11+'_':print' '*35+'|'+c*8+'|'

# 119
s=40
while s:s+=10-s/4;exec(52-s)/3*r"s-=1;print' '*s+'/'+'**'*(39-s)+'\\';"
for c in'-'*11+'_':print' '*35+'|'+c*8+'|'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>101</s> <s>100</s> <s>99</s> <s>90</s> <s>81</s> 66 bytes

```
jbm+*;-39d++\/*\**2d\\s.e+L*3kb+L4TV11+J*35ds_B"|----";+Js_B"|____
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyspV1vLWtfYMkVbO0ZfK0ZLyyglJqZYL1XbR8s4O0nbxyQkzNBQ20vL2DSlON5JqUYXCJSstb3AnHgg@P8fAA)

---

Python 3.8 translation:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
B = lambda G, H: (H, G(H))
r = lambda s: s[::-1]

print("\n".join(map(lambda d: " "*(39-d)+"/"+"*"*(2*d)+"\\", reduce(add, 
map(lambda e: list(map(lambda d: 3*e[0]+d, range(e[1]))), enumerate(map(lambda d: 4+d, range(10))))))))
for N in range(11):
    print((J:=" "*35)+reduce(add, B(r, "|----")))
print(J+reduce(add, B(r, "|____")))
```

Comment: Isn't the `a` function defined in your Python equivalent to `+` on lists?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit It's close, but not exactly: `<list>+<str>` is not a valid operation, but I could just as easily use `["-"]*11+["_"]`. I decided to define my own function to more accurately translate what Pyth is actually doing.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 88 bytes

```powershell
0..9|%{(3*$_)..(3+$_*4)|%{' '*(39-$_)+"/$('**'*$_)\"}}
,'-'*10+'_'|%{' '*35+"|$($_*8)|"}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy 118

```
10.times{(it*3).upto 3+it*4,{println' '*(39-it)+'/'+'*'*it*2+'\\'}};12.times{println' '*35+'|'+(it>10?'_':'-')*8+'|'}
```

Comment: Why am I not surprised to see a pretty short Groovy solution. My impression of Groovy was that it was done by a Java programmer who hated typing.

Answer (score 1):

## C,194

This code is a hot mess and can definitely be golfed more. Still, it was an opportunity to try out a couple of things I've never done before: using a literal for a string of asterisks, and using the width specifier `*` with a string in `printf`.

```
i,j=5,k=5,n;
main(){
  char d[]={[0 ...77]=42,0};
  for(;i<85;i++)k--,j+=!k,k+=(j-1)*!k,n=39-i+(j-5)*(j-4)/2,printf("%*s/%s\\\n",n,"",d+n*2);
  for(;i<97;i++)printf("%*s|\n",44,i-96?"|--------":"|________");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket <strike>223 220 211 204</strike> 198

Golfed:

```
(for-each display(flatten(let([m make-list])`(,(for*/list([i 10][j(range(* i 3)(* 4(+ 1 i)))])`(,(m(- 39 j)" ")"/",(m j"**")"\\\n")),(for/list([c`(,@(m 11"-")"_")])`(,(m 35" ")"|",(m 8 c)"|\n"))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(for-each display
     (flatten
      (let([m make-list])
        `(,(for*/list([i 10][j(range(* i 3)(* 4(+ 1 i)))])
             `(,(m(- 39 j)" ")"/",(m j"**")"\\\n"))
          ,(for/list([c`(,@(m 11"-")"_")])
             `(,(m 35" ")"|",(m 8 c)"|\n"))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), <s>768</s> <s>671</s> <s>659</s> <s>655</s> 654 bytes

```
.text
.globl main
main:
li $8 32
li $9 47
li $t2 42
li $t3 92
li $t4 10
li $t5 42
addi $sp -4
move $4 $sp
la $s6 q
la $s5 w
li $t8 0
li $s0 10
li $t9 0
li $s3 40
li $s2 39
q:
sub $s3 $s3 $t8
add $s2 $s2 $t8
addi $t7 $t8 3
addi $t8 1
blt $s0 $t8 e
r:
sw $0 ($4)
blt $t9 $s2 t
beq $t9 $s2 y
beq $t9 $s3 u
beqz $t7 i
sb $t2 ($4)
p:
li $2 4
syscall
addi $t9 1
ble $t9 $s3 r
move $t9 $0
j $s5
o:
addi $t7 -1
bgez $t7 r
jr $s6
w:
addi $s2 -1
addi $s3 1
j o
t:
sb $8 ($4)
j p
y:
sb $9 ($4)
j p
u:
sb $t4 1($4)
sb $t3 ($4)
j p
i:
sb $t5 ($4)
j p
e:
li $t1 124
li $t3 124
li $t2 45
li $t5 95
li $t7 11
la $s6 a
la $s5 o
li $s2 35
li $s3 44
j r
a:
li $2 10
syscall
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVHLcoQgELzPV8zBQ3LYLRXMin@jWWpLC@MDNhvz8wZmQHNAu3ugB6bt3I/7fnX6x8H1YabO4Nj2XxA@DZgesxpFSUChvBFwJUqWnEAVkcQiZ1SFanu/e2xnvEgYp2@NmQwUTOt/H7gwqPDFZ2rkwzY/bFSSBMqIShQKlgbssyOdlqtDM6rSYh4cbmQsEq2xgM44ahKYhtVbvTDL8S2T71zzbYOLg04vB9v@MYHPwH7Jvwfb0TzIYOaB@emA3exna0xqrai1PizWOJNAcxjCJGBqzntf/PaH5h4rDGuYGbzSBn8jvyFi4a0HnMA1dJearzLgDBsr6lSerISsSCMiznof69UpaX6TK7AoZcr8gP6pVQpdRXTDokgxtynm6QiwOkKVvsEKbRqazz1Obd//AA)

**Edit:** Saved ~100 bytes by hard coding each character in a register and simply writing to the stack, then abusing the fact that MIPS doesn't have types so implicit word to ascii string is allowed.
**Edit 2:** removed duplicate stack alloc. (`addi $sp -4`) Oops!
**Edit 3:** in rewrite, accidently made the tree stump 1 character too short. (36 in stead of 35). Fixed.
**Edit 4:** -4 bytes by using $8 and $9 instead of $t0 and $t1. they mean the same thing, but $t0 is easier to read. unfortunately, all other t registers are the same length when written nicely ($t2 == $10, but both are 3 characters), so the rest are a wash. I could (in theory) use the remaining 'a' registers (5-7. print syscall uses 4), but afaik the behavior isn't defined when using syscall.
-1 Byte by setting t8 to 0 and branching on less than instead of on equal. also required me to reorder the add ops, which unfortunately made the execution time take a whopping 3 opcodes longer.

Not the best at MIPS, but after clearing my conscience of this in meta discussion, i'm submitting them.  MIPS is not designed for this (no output, no for loops) but it's pretty fun to do this perhaps in spite of that.

Unfortunately, I haven't created a commented version for this new solution, but you can view the old version, with full documentation [here](https://tio.run/##dVffb@M2En7XXzGwCnS3SZR4k93D@W6fevfQoi2KboDeQ4EDLdEWN7KoJanY3vb@9r1vhqQsu@lDYpsazs9vvhn5wey@fKkaFRQVvlO@XVGlfG3MZ1rcLope7zvT69nhb7/1i0L5oJ3xT7PzbxaFH1Q9F6VFMfaNdhca/rso1srNDv6Qg5/0/odzwT/YVHPu082iqII@hKKotp1dd7RTpk9H/HVVlBvrXpk@0IHe090/8PFPWvLn1dVrMp6cHbdtd6S9MyHonpRfFZ2hr/wdxKjcqQN11g5U2xFKoIxCqykeViIZ7uhmSWU9OpfOySDOQ1Tzhu7/TqUPjnxQLsTDe3q4i4e6b6KSJd1FHRpmvm2VK4oD61pRUZS4AFfZMGoSqMZjVSPn0RD@yzNn95VYTLIb4yBse41fKvBpbwMpksJU0KuaJvoP9yWqq6spQv6MMfpxLS7LH4RFNDitae1UX7faU2Ohdq@Na8huNl4HWh9FSw7IwFkVjO3xnA4VnsGbVvVNp714V7Ez4rz8sRkPC2ptn3VVrPUnOeOqNPbRjf1Tct4v5cF9UXQKv/5Gn0btjt9OCSoHi@LjS7CXjxabsa/Zp0W8@44k4WdXUp0pSrwlNMAjIv/F7s/EcEx8HkuAgg2OIaf4N0c8FcxX9DhLy6yQnuw6ALG6oWejJHknB7nCCK4i1R9RPl0b1XEO@61n85z@IFcAJ7aX0EDK6ZTlhiuS9UV1byv6tQXiGyDkmmrVdfTVu@KYQPdRdU4SWsoTgUS@7oN10BidIqe3hgmgog98jmQcAnGTs8Dg7NapXVSfJa/JW0AChz3Owuh6jkIwMdnYZ9cqdoViQkuvdgCFj7i4pvUYaG9CK@5FkaygyuheMrpNXzu945SHl9JfrDstoozxY0SB2bwsy6UCagW2/Qs9iVTaPph@1PLwmLpoB4ejCUDb4onbG48QnOZ2@QtL3N1VLsXbl0qx17ka3LCStNRbw6B7X53ahDmq0fM0HGfMhvIV663@LKKnDIh6A6Otgvs7Li9wJaDbmN74VgJgYjsL9qOTfip1xyHu9de4N4PZZQQTBqqiOHXYisqIXZoIZ6sDMrulN5RHjkf9MVNIq7oVyDd2P9UeTHKzzN/vaVl8TKYe7Q@2pjISZDDAFAeq9fxxBYR@DaTVYYTPxxi83mxMbTiBmCloqaD9a04G0qoCkHkKSyjXm92Aq40Fy3FOnKJXoicLdLjlXkcoSWrQFRIKO4VsCKbjQHpDD1Q@ZG7PJOCPXu71427NXMRKd1r1njIFYcogZaDxJFnaMQyjjIMZNYjOI5K6uyaAqNZZc3WRNJCbHV2aLajHDK6o/dM4XE8jBO0@dspJ6SpiDofNtfKmloQCXorev6d1VZwz8yrx/VIqKOjiZwmQjCXxVlAXByBb7G1/I5MNHDuh7HbmHvoswnxSfs98GVW/QCyXbS1Eg30HZBFO3rHFv1QhV9iX0wBAHjY2hXALpa1BtZmnk@8yaR4mfDNIe04X0oqPtaqfGG/5MShcnyAa1BN@Nc@qD2qreRDwnZvQypKDusIMSk5by6hQZtuGSLxTC6JXHHPbiUWxfCSotbobkMbp0amU16zCaXRL2FsECLIwFqH6cRisC7pZweSjvRbj0VJK5/dy9L3qhEdgKJhn3R2ryGRoyr3qxUep6Ky9@JpwEhom@a4Puh75YVHiwp49utHP8BhqOr0JvJrkVSlzbdbHJEWj1@xKFUvHgwy9wfnRCU3Ke73DqHAzSqtSCQHtPTcf2pzbndmDvDqi78fdICWjZ9WNejY81Wl0FuUvKrd2a5oGwf/43c8fJoFEJ3zVnwVwXreKfrIhrXs9eFnndHtpVaGe2oKTUDc8jCDlpRA8hUJxrjltVTHr@FURmasoignsoOZtmlpyNusyTrZVDYcP/ongekClT7P/PF@ZlkCgjU8DzB2Z5HFZOCy3hFg6ZyO4lNlhxfs0M8LkynSP32Mu76XGxy1emf50J73oXN5Kuyfbau3YcXZ77vrADYU6V5HqIz1x3Qd4VE0vAu@yj2lt9zi6HDP3b2MSDG913kK5HTAMzGdZnz3951/TK8RD5JwZ1XAsaWno4tRfYuov38jQrrg2@mBi3WTEI/9YC0yPwihZHO9kNYMcr2bcD@C6zwR2ld2Am47RIo2huOPAIohUY@SXvMaMw/lsTytyYjXsikCNZDAyZsZQbQHmOpauyss4xyLFibudrJF5DT@b4mnIXrJAZjZGFy@nmZ6frWlevabf/8ctWJe39W19dXX7UT0rVDttPhzoaauJO01RYtHAYlfz6m3TAPzz8IsdtY/1WNsQ7G7O/jdgTfQAv8Ze0/Q6XBXzxJzPP8jL6@B8bOHs3xHALw8jFo6rnJjgF2k5juBuXuiHZGWVRPDzBYlkcyaU3tIvZc@sZvEp2kvp8sPP3/2Io0@jYXobZb3MvLBgxC74hL9U8RUW53qH3SLwlGksitvxMOOlwj1J06DQADpo0UfWk1Wt4rbP29TyLq9ExZcv/wc)

Feel free to take the credit and improve upon this answer if you can beat it - I'm probably missing a few optimizations here and there.

Comment: since this solution doesn't require .data, it's possible to convert to binary (compiled) and save a bunch of bytes. however, SPIM doesn't support it, so c'est la vie.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the shorthand `addi $sp -4` which is really `addi $sp $sp -4` is from SPIM or MIPS in general, so if anyone else does, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 40 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ａ｛３＋｛╷¹╷３×＋*×/×｝］⁵-＊_∔｛４×|×］∔｛║Ｌ»‾◂∔ ××］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjIxJXVGRjVCJXVGRjEzJXVGRjBCJXVGRjVCJXUyNTc3JUI5JXUyNTc3JXVGRjEzJUQ3JXVGRjBCKiVENy8lRDcldUZGNUQldUZGM0QldTIwNzUtJXVGRjBBXyV1MjIxNCV1RkY1QiV1RkYxNCVENyU3QyVENyV1RkYzRCV1MjIxNCV1RkY1QiV1MjU1MSV1RkYyQyVCQiV1MjAzRSV1MjVDMiV1MjIxNCUyMCVENyVENyV1RkYzRA__,v=8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 114 bytes

```sh
0 5()<<<${(l:4$0:)1}$2
eval '(repeat '{4..13}' 0 /$S $S\\&&S+=*;);S+=***;' \;{a..l}';5 "|${(l:8::-:)}|"' '|tr - _'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczBCoIwHAfgu0/xw4b/zdjSUohtXXuBXQchNOigEGodcnv2RZ2@2/dZHpkXS1ghr7lBz4W1lm181B1rtGgTOxbhPYwgPodnGFbQ1inVnhKhwYE5MOd9Vbn9pTbC/KhrQ/BmG5QaE5keZfyHZ62lFimWBIrrDIkbZYFdnO798pryFw)

Explanation:

- `0 5()`: define a function under both the names `0` and `5`

  - `<<<`: print
  - `${1}`: the first argument,
  - `(l:4$0:)`: left-padded with spaces to the length:

    - `$0`: the name of the function
    - `4`: with a 4 prepended
    - so if this function is called by the name `0`, it will use length 40; if `5`, then 45
  - `$2`: with the second argument appended
- `eval`uate the following string as `zsh` code (you can replace the `eval` with `echo` to see the generated code string is):

  - `{4..13}`: repeat the string `(repeat X 0 /$S $S\\&&S+=*;);S+=***;` multiple times with the numbers from `4` to `13` each in place of the `X`. The meaning of the string

    - `repeat N`: do this `N` times:

      - `0`: call the function with first argument {a `/` plus the variable `$S`} and second argument {the variable `$S` plus a backslash `\\`}
      - `&&`: then
      - `S+=*;`: append a `*` to the variable `$S`
    - `)`: reset all variables (importantly `$S`) to their values before the `(`
    - `S+=***;`: append `***` to `$S`
  - `{a..l}`: repeat the string `;X;5 "|${(l:8::-:)}|"` : repeat this string with the letters from `a` to `l` each in place of the `X`

    - each letter is just a nonexistent command which is ignored; the `{a..l}` here just makes the code execute 12 times
    - `5`: call the function with the first argument `|${(l:8::-:)}|` (and no second argument)

      - `${(l:8::-:)}`: left-pad {nothing} to length 8 with dashes `-`
      - `"||"`: surrounded by pipes
  - `|tr - _`: replace the dashes with underscores. This only applies to the last call to `5`, so only the last line of the trunk is drawn with underscores, because the repeated string `;X;5 "|${(l:8::-:)}|"` has the semicolons at the start to separate the commands.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 526 bytes

```
+>+[[-]<-[>+++>+<<-]>>+[<<+>>-]<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]<<<[>>---->+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[[-]>>>--[<+>++++++]<---<<<[>+>>-<<<-]>[<+>-]>>[<<+>>-]++++[<++++++++>-]<<-[>.<-]+++[>+++++<-]>.-----<<[>+<-]>[<+>>..<-]-[>+<-----]>-.<-[>-<---]>+++.[-]<<+[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]<<<[>>---->+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<]<[-]<[>+>+<<-]>>+[<<+>>-]<----------]<+[>+>+<<-]>>-[<<+>>-]<[[-]>>--[<<-->-->+++++++]<----<-[>.<-]-[>+<---]>+++++++.-<++++[>-------<-]<[>+<-]>[[<+>-]-[>-<-----]>+<]++++[>..<-]>[-]--[<+>--]<---.>-[<-->+++++++++]<.[-]<[>+>+<<-]>>-[<<+>>-]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVBBCgJBDHvQkL6g9CNlDioIIngQfP/YtDs7u97sbZJJ2uT6vjxe98/tOUaz5o6ucGstHqroFphqMws84AnumAZqiCGTFDmSqfBEAA@k5YQ9kDIalIbs0ZX/Atsm18RNosl4GVEnXIz0mjYm/IZEON0gFEPzEUJhRG3/h4k45xJWM9inn5yxussmWER8Nm441IEZb97dJy3IGtw2e60LMm21NrOlSKu6KsFiZTWPOlF4z1rN5fITaR3cx/gC)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 55 bytes

```
x39_;ḤØ1jƊƲ}
⁵Ḷµ+4Ḷ++Ḥ“ /*\”çⱮYð€;ø“ |-|”ẋ12”_-¦s4ç€4µY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/C2DLe@uGOJYdnGGYd6zq2qZbrUePWhzu2HdqqbQKktLWBco8a5ijoa8U8aph7ePmjjesiD2941LTG@vAOkHiNbg1Q/OGubkMjIB2ve2hZsQlQVdMak0NbI///BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 166 <s>228</s> <s>260</s>

```cobra
class P
    def main
        for x in 10,for n in 4+x,print' '.repeat(39-x*3-n)+'/['**'.repeat(x*3+n)]\\'
        w=' '.repeat(35)
        print'[w]|--------|\n'.repeat(11)+w+'|________|'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python (313)

```
'eJztmEsOwjAMBfecoutIFUfiIjk8FAJNE3+eE0sI6qxnRq3jVZYFOlcQSwnlMPIJeqOFRNgPCsAVq9MH+Lvxhtb4DlcEgpcNUvjBr2IMyWEVQRIc3hKlk/2VYnGeqjEi4NEmJMZwrCpoUi6sErLB7W2THKPGXe9RG+3WN+tNYMA/FoYCcX9/dH+DhboxnKgiE429MhWJ3egSsRttZrLy7kxnSsih8yq5hGL9+Eqsn1TyWz+n0tZySz1ijq2UXGPQi1pey8mXoM9F38rJd5RXZaM='.decode('base64').decode('zip')
```

Comment: Doesn't output anything. With `print`,the backslashes and linefeeds seem to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>163</s> <s>160</s> 159 bytes

-3 -1 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

```c
j,w,s[99];main(i){for(;++i<12;w-=i-1)for(j=i+2;j--;)printf("%*c%.*s\\\n",40-w++,47,w*2,memset(s,42,99));for(;i--;)printf("%44s|\n",i?"|--------":"|________");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBCsIwEAD/Eigkza7YEJC4Fh9iRCS0soVGaQo5WN8eqfTiHAdmAj5CKGWADOni3JXGO0fJ6t0/J0la86kxlLFlbNSqhpa1oQGR1GviOPdSVHWodnXy3kcBdo9Za7AHyLWBsRtTN8sE1oBzStHvyn@1tWlZSz6LBTfEUSy3DaHoU8oX)

Comment: Is limiting the number of printed string characters by using `"%.*s"` in a `printf` call standard behaviour?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Yep, should be. "If the
precision is specified, no more than that many bytes are written." - §7.21.6.1 of [this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). (It regards fprintf, but the section on printf states that the format string works the same way as for fprintf.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 56 bytes

```
4Ḷ4ịr+L}¥¥Ɗ9Ð¡ẎḤ”*ẋ⁾/\jÐ€;⁾-_x11,1¤ẋ8⁾||jƊ€¤µLH40_⁶ẋ;µ€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/k4Y5tJg93dxdp@9QeWnpo6bEuy8MTDi18uKvv4Y4ljxrmaj3c1f2ocZ9@TNbhCY@a1lgD2brxFYaGOoaHlgClLID8mpqsY11AuUNLDm318TAxiH/UuA0oZX1oK1Aw8v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>140 138</s> 136 bytes

```php
while($n--||30>$w+=3-$n=3+$i++)echo($p=str_pad)("",39-$w),$p("/",1|2*$w++,"*"),"\\
";while(-~$i)echo$p("",35),$p("|",9,$i--?"-":_),"|
";
```

less golfed:

```php
for(;$i<10;$w-=$i)for($n=3+$i++;$n--;)
    echo str_pad("",39-$w), str_pad("/",1+2*$w++,"*"),"\\\n";
for($i++;$i--;)
    echo str_pad("",35), str_pad("|",9,$i?"-":_),"|\n";
```

Run with `php -nr '<code>'` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b790a3bbfa7b27a066a4531a60fae9dfed91057). Requires PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>51</s> <s>50</s> <s>49</s> 48 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ao*3 cÈôY+3@'\i'/+Xç*²
cCÆ'|i|+8ç"-_"gXzB})û mx1
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=QW8qMyBjyPRZKzNAJ1xpJy8rWOcqsgpjQ8YnfGl8KzjnIi1fImdYekJ9KfsgbXgx)

```
Ao*3 cÈôY+3@'\i'/+Xç*²
A                             :10
 o                            :Range [0,A)
  *3                          :Multuply each by 3
     c                        :Flatten after ...
      È                       :  Map each X at 0-based index Y
       ôY+3                   :    Sorted range [X,X+Y+3]
           @                  :    Map each X
            '\i               :      Prepend "\" with
               '/+            :        "/" appended with
                  Xç          :          X times repeat
                    *²        :            "*" repeated twice
```

```
cCÆ'|i|+8ç"-_"gXzB})û mx1
c                             :Concatenate
 C                            :  12
  Æ                           :  Map each X in the range [0,C)
   '|i                        :    Prepend "|" with
      |+                      :      "|" appended with
        8ç                    :        8 times repeat
          "-_"g               :          Get the character in "-_" at index
               Xz             :            X floor divided by
                 B            :              11
                  }           :  End map
                   )          :End concat
                    û         :Centre pad each element with spaces to the length of the longest
                      m       :Map
                       x1     :  Trim right
                              :Implicit output, joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 36 bytes

```
TLεÌÝN3*+'*×'/ì]˜…|--11и…|__ªº€¨«º.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xOfc1sM9h@f6GWtpq2sdnq6uf3hN7Ok5jxqW1ejqGhpe2AFixccfWnVo16OmNYdWHFp9aJde8v//AA)

```
TLε            ]       # for y in [1 .. 10]
   ÌÝ                  #  [0 .. y+2]
     N                 #  0-based iteration count (effectively y-1)
      3*               #  times 3
        +              #  add (vectorizes over the range, yielding [3*y-3 .. 4*y-1])
         '*×           #  "*" repeated that many times (vectorizes)
            '/ì        #  prepend "/" (vectorizes)
˜                      # flatten
 …|--                  # literal "|--"
     11и               # repeated 11 times as an array
        …|__           # literal "|__"
            ª          # appended to that array
             º         # mirror (vectorizes: ["|----|", "|----|", ..., "|____|")
              €¨       # remove the last character of each
                «      # merge the two lists (["/", "/*", ..., "|----", ...])
                 º     # mirror
                  .c   # center
```

Answer (score 0):

## Deadfish~, 5411 bytes

```
{iii}ii{ccc}ccccccccc{i}iiiiic{iiii}iiiiic{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}cccccccc{i}iiiiicdddddcc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccccc{i}iiiiicdddddcccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}cccccc{i}iiiiicdddddcccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}cccccc{i}iiiiicdddddcccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{i}iiiiicdddddcccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}cccc{i}iiiiicddddd{c}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccc{i}iiiiicddddd{c}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}cc{i}iiiiicddddd{c}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccc{i}iiiiicddddd{c}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}cc{i}iiiiicddddd{c}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}c{i}iiiiicddddd{c}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}{i}iiiiicddddd{c}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}ccccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}cccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}{i}iiiiicddddd{c}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}ccccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}cccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}ccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}cccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}ccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}cccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}ccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}cccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}ccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}cccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}ccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}cc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}c{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}cccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}ccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}cc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}c{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}c{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{cc}{i}iiiiicddddd{ccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}c{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}ccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}c{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}cc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}c{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{c}{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiicddddd{cccccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccccc}{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccccc}cc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccccc}cccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiicddddd{ccccccc}cccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{iiii}dddcddddd{ccccccc}cccccccc{iiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}icccccccc{{i}dd}dc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}ii{ccc}ccccc{{i}d}iic{ddd}icccccccc{iii}dc
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 39 bytes

```
₀ƛ‹3*n4*rƛ×*\/pøṀ;;\|4-mw11ẋ\|\_4*+mJJf
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=C&code=%E2%82%80%C6%9B%E2%80%B93*n4*r%C6%9B%C3%97*%5C%2Fp%C3%B8%E1%B9%80%3B%3B%5C%7C4-mw11%E1%BA%8B%5C%7C%5C_4*%2BmJJf&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
₀ƛ                ;                     # 1...10 map...
        r                               # Range between...
  ‹3*                                   # 3(n - 1)
        r                               # And...
     n4*                                # 4n (excluded)
         ƛ       ;                      # Map to...
          ×*                            # That many asterisks
            \/p                         # Prepend a backslash
               øṀ                       # Ascii-art mirror
                         11ẋ            # 11 copies of...
                   \|4-mw               # '|--------|'
                            \|\_4*+mJ   # And a '|________|'
                                     Jf # Append to the original and flat the whole thing
                                        # (C flag) center and join by newlines
```